# Unable to Set Radio Button value when two windows are opened using the same ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm using the following control template in two windows that are opened at the same time and both using the SAME viewmodel.
Here is the template;

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SecurityTypeSelectionTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton GroupName ="SecurityType"  Content="Equity" 
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=SecurityType, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Equity}" />
            <RadioButton GroupName ="SecurityType" Content="Fixed Income" 
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=SecurityType, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=FixedIncome}" />
            <RadioButton GroupName ="SecurityType" Content="Futures" 
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=SecurityType, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=Futures}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Here is the viewmodel property:

```
    private SecurityTypeEnum _securityType;
    public SecurityTypeEnum SecurityType
    {
        get { return _securityType; }
        set
        {
            _securityType = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SecurityType");
        }
    }
```

Here's the Enum:

```
public enum SecurityType { Equity, FixedIncome, Futures }
```

Here is the converter:

```
public class EnumToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object enumTarget, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string enumTargetStr = enumTarget as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(enumTargetStr))
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        if (Enum.IsDefined(value.GetType(), value) == false)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        object expectedEnum = Enum.Parse(value.GetType(), enumTargetStr);

        return expectedEnum.Equals(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object enumTarget, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string expectedEnumStr = enumTarget as string;
        if (expectedEnumStr == null)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        return Enum.Parse(targetType, expectedEnumStr);
    }
}
```

The problem is a bit strange.  I have two windows that are showing slightly different views of the SAME ViewModel.  The same template shown above is reused in both views.
If Equity is initially set as SecurityType, i can change this to FixedIncome by clicking on the relevant radio button.  I can not then change it back to Equity.
I can however set it to Futures.  But then after that, i can not change it to either FixedIncome or Equity by clicking the relevant radio buttons.
What's happening in the cases where i can not set change it back is that the Setter is called twice.  the first time it's setting the value to the correct selected value, but the moment RaisePropertyChanged is fired,
the setter is invoked again, this time with the original value.
It feels like when RaisePropertyChanged, the the setter is being called by the binding from the 2nd window, thus overwriting the value being set in the first window where the user makes the selection.
Does anyone know if this is the case and how to avoid in this scenario?

Comment: what does your EnumBoolConverter look like? I had that same problem once and discovered it was my converter messing up everything, but I can't remember exactly what the problem was.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the converter.

Comment: Mike: look at my answer. The `EnumToBoolConverter` should return a bool in the `ConvertBack`. Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version of EnumToBoolConverter:

```
public class EnumToBoolConverter : BaseConverterMarkupExtension<object, bool>
    {
        public override bool Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return false;

            return value.Equals(Enum.Parse(value.GetType(), (string)parameter, true));
        }

        public override object ConvertBack(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter)
        {
            return value.Equals(false) ? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue : parameter;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed the problem.  so both Convert and ConvertBack returns a boolean in this case?  it's a bit non-intuitive when you think of the word "Convert Back"...but it makes some sense now that i'm forced to think about it, i think.   Thanks much!

Comment: No, my mistake. Actually ConvertBack returns the `parameter` value (which is actually a String, only when trying to "Convert Back" the `RadioButton.IsChecked = true` to Enum. I guess the binding framework is capable of converting a string to an Enum value by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for a RadioButton is to update the source when the property changes so both windows are trying to update the source.  One fix is to only update the source only from where the user clicked.  To do this use [Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) Explict on the binding.  Add a click handler in code behind for RadioButton.  In it explicity update the source.

```
        <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton GroupName ="SecurityType"  Content="Equity" 
                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=SecurityType, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ConverterParameter=Equity}" Click="RadioButton_Click" />
        <RadioButton GroupName ="SecurityType" Content="Fixed Income" 
                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=SecurityType, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ConverterParameter=FixedIncome}" Click="RadioButton_Click"/>
        <RadioButton GroupName ="SecurityType" Content="Futures" 
                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=SecurityType, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ConverterParameter=Futures}" Click="RadioButton_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>  

    private void RadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingExpression be = ((RadioButton)sender).GetBindingExpression(RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty);
        be.UpdateSource();
    }
```

You may have to use a UserControl instead of or inside your ControlTemplate to get code behind in your view.

Comment: thanks. i had tried this initially, but i do want the other window to update when the newly selected option, so this solution did not do that for me.

Comment: For this case the EnumToBoolConverter is the answer because it is simplest.  UpdateSourceTrigger may help someone else though.  The main point is UpdateSourceTrigger gives you control over when the update to the binding source occurs.  As presented here it specifically does update the other windows when a newly selected option is selected in one window by the user via the RadioButton_Click event.